# Install Clang 3.1

Tags: macos, mac, xcode

What would be the best place to manually install llvm/clang binaries in OS X 10.7 without conflicting with existing/future versions shipped with xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual place to install your own compiled libraries etc and make them available for all users is /usr/local (Except if you use Homebrew package manager which uses this directory)

Apple can overwrite any directory that is in /System or /Library or /Applications so don't use these, but you can use anything else.

see [Apple development document on FileSystem basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) for more detail.